# How do I add someone to a Twilio Conversation Channel?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-conversations

I'm using the [Twilio Javascript Conversations SDK](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/1.1.0/docs/index.html), and I'm migrating from the old Programmable Chat API.

My question is, how do I add another user to the chat? The programmable chat feature had the `invite` method, but that's not a method in the conversations API. I also tried using the "add" method, but that's not working either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invites, Conversations require us to add users as "participants".
You can use the **add** method from the Conversation object.
You'll need to pass the identity of the user.

http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/1.1.0/docs/Conversation.html#add__anchor